# Why doesn't ChatGPT ask questions?

Tags: natural-language-processing, chatgpt, natural-language-generation

As far as I understand ChatGPT has been trained on a vast array of data, and it *does understand* questions; but it seems to never ask. Even if a person would ask clarifying questions (that I assume are in the train set) ChatGPT doesn't, opting instead to invent context or just say "X depends on Y, Z"...

Not asking questions seems trained into the network, but I am not sure how one would go about training a model not to generate questions in such a way that not even in DAN mode it doesn't. I understand that for toxic language GPT-3 uses human raters to generate a train set and then optimizes for non toxic behavior, but it seems to specific to be used for the general concept of questions.

Comment: It seems to be asking questions if you guide it to do so

Comment: @Crantisz what text did you use to make it ask questions for clarification?

Comment: "Guess what I riddled, ask leading questions, I'll answer yes or no"

Comment: With DAN I can also use "ask leading questions" for general topics, I will check if I can get it to ask for more information about a request